# How to center slider animation on tkinter Toplevel?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I seem to have an ongoing struggle with centering matplotlib slider animations in figure canvases that are embedded in Toplevel windows. My function takes as parameters a C-by-N matrix, M, where N is quite large, a list of C channels, and a positive integer win_size, small in comparison to N. The animation appears on a Toplevel window. Each frame of the animation will show a heatmap of a C-by-win_size matrix, where the precise set of columns depends upon the slider value. For example, if M is 4-by-300 and win_size=10, frame 0 will be the heatmap of M[:,0:10] with x-axis labels 0 to 10, frame 1 will be the heatmap of M[:,10:20] with x-axis labels 10 to 20, and so on. The y-axis labels in each frame are the channel labels.

Here's the function:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from tkinter import Tk,TOP,BOTH,Toplevel
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg',force=True)

from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import mpl_toolkits
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

def scrolling_matrix_viewer(M,channels,win_size):
    
    plot_window = Toplevel(bg="lightgray") #Toplevel where animation is embedded
    plot_window.geometry('1000x900')
    plot_window.wm_title('Top Level Window')
    plot_window.attributes('-topmost', 'true')

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.05, bottom=0.07, right=0.95, top=0.95, wspace=0, hspace=0)    
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=plot_window)
    canvas.draw()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP,fill=BOTH,expand=1)
    
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MaxNLocator(10))
    ax.invert_yaxis

    plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=.2, right=None, top=.9, wspace=.2, hspace=.2)
    ax_time=fig.add_axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03]) # axis for slider

    # add colorbar to right of animation
    ax_divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
    cax = ax_divider.append_axes('right', size='7%', pad='2%')
    spos = Slider(ax_time, '',valinit=0,valmin=0,valmax=M.shape[1]-win_size,valstep=win_size)

    def update_graph(val):
            start=spos.val # starting column index of M used for this frame
            stop=spos.val+win_size # ending column index of M used for this frame
            if stop<=M.shape[1]:
               ax.cla
               heatmap=ax.imshow(M[:,start:stop],vmin=0, vmax=1, cmap='coolwarm', 
               aspect='auto',extent=[0,win_size,M.shape[0],0])
               cb = fig.colorbar(heatmap, cax=cax, orientation='vertical')
               ax_time.set_xlabel('time (sec)',fontsize=12)
               ax.set_ylabel('channel',fontsize=12)
               ticks=ax.get_xticks()
               x_labels=[str(start+ticks[i]) for i in range(len(ticks))] 
               ax.set_xticklabels(x_labels)
               ax.set_yticks(range(len(channels)))
               ax.set_yticklabels(channels,fontsize=12)

    spos.on_changed(update_graph)
    spos.set_val(0)
```

Now, an example where M is 4-by-300 and win_size=10:

```
root=Tk()

M=np.random.rand(4,300)
channels=['A','B','C','D']
win_size=10
scrolling_matrix_viewer(M,channels,win_size)

root.mainloop()
```

Here's what one frame of the resulting animation looks like:

[image]

As you can see, the result is not centered within the Toplevel window. I've experimented much with the above plot adjustments but haven't figured out what modification will center the animation.

Comment: Your code as provided needs some modification to run properly. Issues are arguments in the `spos = Slider` line and using `ticks` when you should be using `xticks`

Comment: @jezza_99--thanks so much for bringing this to my attention. I've made some edits to the code so it should work.

Comment: you create the left margin by `plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, ...`, don't you?

Comment: Essentially, yes. However, changing its parameters requires adjusting the slider location in order to keep the slider centered under heat plot. (As opposed to centered under the heat plot and colorbar combined.)

The best I've been able to do through experimentation is to set

```fig.subplots_adjust(left=.09, bottom=.2, right=None, top=.9, wspace=.2, hspace=.2)```    

```ax_time=fig.add_axes([0.15, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03]) ```

Would love to find a way to do this without all the fine-tuning.